# Scraping and print all names and tags on web based on specific tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

all names on my HTML link have one tag ok? (i use beautiful soup)
I want to scrape and print all names with their tags if their tags ==
'specific string' ok?

my classes name is div

my id names = 'name'

my id tags = 'tag'

and my code is this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://aaaaaaaaa.org/plus')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all(id={'name', 'tag'})
for item in res:
    print(item.text.strip())
```

my output is this:

```
General English: Intermediate
bbb
General English: Elementary
AAAAAAAAAAA
General English: Intermediate Plus
bbbbbbb
General English: Beginner
ggg
TOEFL iBT: Listening and Speaking
bbbbbbbb
TOEFL iBT: Reading
AAAAAAAAAAA
Grammar for IELTS
AAAAAAAAAAA
```

but i want just if tags == AAAAAAAAAAA give me name of tags with tag ok?
Like the following:

```
General English: Elementary
AAAAAAAAAAA
TOEFL iBT: Reading
AAAAAAAAAAA
Grammar for IELTS
AAAAAAAAAAA
```

please help me and tnx for your help :)

Comment: Please provide a valid `url`.

Comment: provide valid url or the html source. no one will write code to reproduce your sample data to test. you'll also get quicker and more reliable responses

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way would be using xpath. You can use lxml library.

```
import lxml.html
import lxml.etree

def html_to_root(html):
    html_parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
    return lxml.etree.HTML(html, parser=html_parser)

 html_tree = html_to_root(resp.content)

 division_you_want = html_tree.xpath('xpath')
```